# AWS - SWF - Asynchronous method

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I have some 4 method calls - independent of each other in an asynchronous method - will all of them run in parallel over different hosts and return their promises or is it done sequentially

Answer (score 0):

They will start in order, but will not necessarily return in that order as they are asynchronous they return without waiting for a return value but instaed use promises to allow the exection of dependent processes. It does mean that any processes waiting for the Promise from that activity will have to wait for it to finish.